# Drawing QPushButton text off the button

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton, qstyle

I am creating a custom QPushButton.  If the button has an icon I want the icon centered on the button.  If the button has text I want the text centered on the button.  I can handle both of those cases.  If the button contains both an icon and text I want the icon centered and the text drawn below the button, outside the button rectangle.  I am drawing the button image using border-image in a stylesheet.

Inside MyPushButton::paintEvent() I calculate a rectangle and draw the icon using:

```
    style()->drawItemPixmap(&p, iconRect, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, 
        this->icon().pixmap(iconRect.size()));
```

I then calculate a text rectangle below the button and do this:

```
    style()->drawItemText(&p, textRect, Qt::AlignCenter, (this->palette()),
        true, this->text(), QPalette::ButtonText );
```

but the text is not visible.

I think this must have something to do with designated "drawable" area, but I can't figure out how to extend that area so that the button image doesn't to fill the area where I want to place the text.

I can do this with a QStyle::drawControl() overload but I'm not sure why.  When I trace the code into the CE_PushButtonLabel case the myStyle->rect has already been resized to be large enough to fit the button image and the text.

Comment: Have you tried using a [QToolButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtoolbutton.html)?

Comment: I looked into QToolButton, but I don't want the text to just appear beneath the icon.  I want it to appear beneath the "apparent" button image.  Imagine placing a QPushButton in Designer.  Adding an "icon" property via the Property list.  Then placing a QLabel underneath the bounds of the button.  But the contents of the QLabel would reflect the "text" property of the button.  I could probably do it this way, but surely there is a way to draw the button background and then change the extent of the button so I can add the text at a specified location?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for `QToolButton` along with `setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)`.

Comment: I want the text under the button.  I want the icon to be displayed on the button and the string returned by this->text() to be drawn beneath, giving the impression that it is a QLabel.  The customer wants a custom button available through QtDesigner that works this way.  When they enter the "text" property that string appears beneath the button while the "icon" appears centered on the button.